# How to put images with captions inside bulleted lists in pandoc

Tags: image, markdown, pandoc, caption

I'm trying to write a pandoc markdown text with an image inside a bulleted list
that also shows captions. That is:

```
* Item 1.
* Item 2.
![This is my caption](image.png "I tried using this as caption too")
Item 2 text is supposed to continue here (thus same indenting).
* Item 3.
```

But the caption doesn't show up.

If I place a figure in its own paragraph the label shows but the
indenting/continuation is messed up.

```
* Item 1.
* Item 2.

![This is my caption](image.png "I tried using this as caption too")

Item 2 text does not continue with the same indenting/continuation : (
* Item 3.
```

My final conversion is a HTML file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paragraphs (and other block level elements) are nested in a list item with indentation. You need to indent the elements one level and wrap with blank lines:

```
* Item 1.
* Item 2.

    ![This is a caption](image.png "This is a title")

    Item 2 text must continue with the same indenting.

* Item 3.
```

Comment: @monteiro if the answer resolved your problem, you can "accept" it.

Comment: I found I needed to indent at least four spaces in multimarkdown.  But nested bullets can have just one additional space per level.  A bit inconsistent, but it worked.